# How to know a sql command which needs how many spool space in tera data?

Tags: teradata

How to  know a sql command   which  needs  how many  spool space in tera data?

If a command like this

```
select * from abc_view;
```

How to get the actual used spool space for above sql command.

Any idea ??  use explain  command ?

```
explain
select * from abc_view;   ???
```

Comment: Explain shows the roughly estimated spool, dbc.QryLogV the actual spool usage (if DBQL is enabled)

Comment: I find a  sample  https://www.revisitclass.com/teradata/how-to-calculate-the-query-execution-time-in-teradata/

Comment: BUT  NO   SPOOL  SPACE.   how  to  get  the  sql  uuid ?

Comment: my  execution result  :    empty  row  ->   https://imgur.com/a/OsjJkpo

Comment: *if DBQL is enabled*. `BEGIN QUERY LOGGING ...`, run the query and wait until it's flushed from cache (or `END|FLUSH QUERY LOGGING...`)

Comment: thanks  but  has a  error message.  see https://imgur.com/a/I2okHcM

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE ON DBC.DBQLAccessMacro TO  nos_usr1;